# TinyMCE 4 obtener id generada para el div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Quisiera saber como puedo conseguir el id que se genera para el div en tinyMCE 4.

Se que se hace a través del método setup, pero no consigo hacerlo.
Uso lo siguiente:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#selector',
    setup: function(editor){
        editor.on('init',function(e){
            console.log();
        });
    }
});
```

Hasta ahí he llegado.
Al crear un `<textarea>` y vincularlo al tinymce, este oculta el textarea y crea en su lugar un div con una id (parecida a esa "mceu_X") y este id es el que quiero conseguir.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder directamente al objeto tinymce. Desde ahí tienes funciones con las que obtener los valores del objeto generado.

Por ejemplo

```
tinymce.editors[0].iframeElement.offsetParent.id;
```

Puedes sustituir el 0 por el objeto en cuestión si tienes varias instancias de tinymce o iterar por todas ellas para recuperar los ids.

Answer (score 0):

En concreto, debes hacer esto:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#selector',
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('init', function(e) {

      // obtener el id
      var id = $('[id^="mceu_"]')[0].id;
      alert(id);
    });
  }
});
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/cqajr61e/

*no lo dejo en un stack-snippet pues no permiten que se cargue tinymce por la política del mismo origen*

#### Explicación

Con jQuery puedes utilizar el selector `^=` conocido como [Comienza con](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (o startsWith).

Ejemplo:

```js
var id = $('[id^="mceu_"]')[0].id;
alert(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="otro" />
<div id="mceu_1234" />
```

Explicación del selector:

- Los `[]`, indican que de quieres buscar en los atributos de los elementos.
- `[id^="VAL"]` lease, cuando el atributo `id` comienza con el literal VAL.

Por otro lado, en JavaScript puro, puedes usar [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) con el mismo selector. A diferencia de JQuery que devuelve un arreglo, esta opción retorna el primer elemento que coincida.

```js
var id = document.querySelector('[id^="mceu_"]').id;
alert(id);
```

```html
<div id="otro"/>
<div id="mceu_1234"/>
```